# Deploying asp.net app with automatic migrations enabbled

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have automatic migration enabled in my asp.net 4.6 mvc 5 web app. I added a custom field to IdentityUser model and when I run the web app I get

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database

I figured that I have to ran Update-Database from Package Manager Console and that resolved it locally in my dev environment. Now, when I deploy the app to an upstream environment (e.g. Azure) how do I trigger updating that database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below code to the Global.asax

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
```